# imap_open Couldn't open stream

Tags: php

I found many answers for imap_open Could not open stream. But no solution worked for me so I'm still asking for other solutions to this problem, that's my code:

**My code**

```
$server = '{localhost:110/pop3}INBOX';
$adresse ='new@harmony.com';
$password = 'edinfredin';
$mbox = imap_open($server,$address,$password,OP_READONLY);
```

**Error message**

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {localhost:110/pop3}INBOX in C:\xampp\htdocs\dankesSeite\readMail.php on line 22
```

Can someone show me another solution?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in C:\xampp\htdocs\dankesSeite\readMail.php on line 22

Comment: Can you edit that into your post please?

Comment: Seems like you try to connect to gmail? Try this for `$server`: `imap.gmail.com`

Comment: I tried it, but that did not work

Comment: You are assigning to `$adresse` but are using `$address`. Change the assignment to `$address`.

Comment: If i Change the assignment to $address it also is not working